# Singular Values of a Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: matrices, svd, singular-values, toeplitz-matrices

I am looking for analytical expressions for the the singular values of a Toeplitz matrix. If possible for a general Toeplitz matrix but I would also take results for a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

\begin{equation}
  A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & a & b \\ & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ & & c & a\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

While I have references for the eigenvalues of such a matrix, e.g. the book by Smith, I am struggling to find expressions for the singular values.

I am aware that if $c=b$ and $A$ is real and symmetric, the singular values are basically the eigenvalues (absolute values of the eigenvalues to be precise). But what if that is not the case?

*Smith, G. D.*, Numerical solution of partial differential equations. Finite difference methods. 2nd ed, Oxford Applied Mathematics and Computing Science Series. Oxford: Clarendon Press. XII, 304 p. hbk: \textsterling 9.00; pbk: \textsterling 4.95 (1978). [ZBL0389.65040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0389.65040).

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Seems interesting but at least at first glance, I did not see an expression for the singular values. I will take another look but may be you could point me to the right equation in the paper?

Comment: I misread. For singular value to equal the eigenvalues, isn't positive semidefiniteness required?

Comment: Yes, you may be right. But that is probably the case if a, b, c are non-zero.

Comment: Not so sure. You need symmetry and diagonal dominance. Think of Gershgorin.